# Clock skew issue : CentOS7

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-errors, ntp

I'm facing clock skew issue while compiling/building C++ package.

we are using soft links from remote drive to local to fetch common packages while building a package as a nightly build. We've also installed NTP server to match both times. We're not facing it always but sometimes.

```
make[1]: warning:  Clock skew detected.  Your build may be incomplete.
make[2]: Warning: File 'Makefile' has modification time 0.00096 s in the future
```

If I build it in everything from the local machine then the build behaves correctly, but for some reason, we can't do that in the CICD process as it takes 3 hours to build. Because of this issue, the compiler could not detect some files.

This app built on QT.

Any suggestions on this? anybody had the same issue before?

Answer (score 0):

This is really a question for [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ntp), and tag [NTP]

We have a large Enterprise config w/multiple VM servers and NFS/SAN storage. While all our servers had NTP, turns out the storage array head end could not reach the NTP server (separate, isolated VLAN). The failure came from the timestamps assigned by the array, not the mounted servers. It would drift into the future. Interestingly, same array hosts the VMs.

We observed iasues even running tar, as well as for detecting changes for aource control and building.

Make sure all your servers point to a valid upstream server, all the way to an authoritative clock. That includes the SAN head devicea and any backup/restore hosts. You can google best practices, but a good suggestion is servers to regerence to the upstream network switch, and those to an internal NTP server (and alternate (or 2 is better)), then those to a common authoritative source. Using LDAP or AD as upstream sources is all OK. That way at least everything in your network segments is synced even if things break.

Use [`ntpq`](http://doc.ntp.org/4.1.0/ntpq.htm) to validate.

Answer (score 0):

Just got to know that our servers are configured with Chronyc.

Here is `chronyc tracking` status

```
Stratum         : 6
Ref time (UTC)  : Mon Feb 22 17:01:00 2021
System time     : 0.000108047 seconds slow of NTP time
Last offset     : +0.000085771 seconds
RMS offset      : 0.001162956 seconds
Frequency       : 89.448 ppm slow
Residual freq   : +0.001 ppm
Skew            : 0.245 ppm
Root delay      : 0.158043087 seconds
Root dispersion : 0.115303792 seconds
Update interval : 1043.7 seconds
Leap status     : Normal
```

Comment: Yout first post said " 0.00096 s in the future " (and this should be an edit to your Q, not an A). This update shows " 0.000108047 seconds slow". So, the gap is narrower. If clocks are out, the time is skewed (slowed or speed up fractionally) until over time they'll aligh to within tolerance. Large gaps (many secs/mins) won't skew. And must be set manually. You can calculate the time it with take. `diff/skewrate`. You can [read about it](http://www.ntp.org/ntpfaq/NTP-s-algo.htm#Q-ALGO-BASIC-SYNC). Just make sure everything points to a common source.